# Textbox with focus does not save the value in the apex variable

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

When a user types a value in a text box and then click the save button without first clicking off of the textbox it doesn't save the value. If I click in the textbox and type out the value and then click out of the text box and then click save it does save the value. I tried removing focus from the active element like so:

```
<apex:commandButton immediate="true" action="{!save}" value="Save" onClick="document.activeElement.blur();" />
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `immediate` attribute. Having immediate skips all getters and setters in your controller.

Comment: Do you have documentation you can reference for that? I thought it bypassed validation only.

Comment: I haven't come across an official piece of documentation around this, I learned it the hard way. But it's logical - in order to skip validation rules and execute a method immediately, it needs to look at the current (immediate) state and avoid applying any changes to the bound variables.